# Can't importing module into nightwatch test using require

Tags: integration-testing, browserify, nightwatch.js

How can I import a module in a nightwatch spec test?

If I try run this nightwatch test:

```
var settings = require("../settings")

module.exports = {
  'Test PCC': function (browser) {


browser. //etc
```

I get undefined is not a function. Do I need to package this with something like browserify?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need browserify to import a module. It should work if the path is correct and the function you call exists.

I am guessing you call 'settings.some_function' in a part of the code that is not shown.

Check if settings itself is defined. If not, then the path could be incorrect or settings does not really export anything.

I have successfully required npm modules and custom local modules with requires without browserify.

Both of these will work if the paths are right and they export correctly:

- var _ = require('underscore');
- var u = require('../../../common/utilities').utilities;

Answer (score 0):

File structure:

```
settings.js
/test.nightwatch.js
```

test.nightwatch.js:

```
var settings = require("../settings");

module.exports = {
  "subTest1" : function(client){
    var a = settings.someProperty;
    settings.someFunction(a);
    //logs "some static parameter" to console

    ...
    //test code
  }
}
```

settings.js:

```
exports.someFunction = function(param){
  console.log(param);
}

exports.someParam = "some static parameter";
```

Comment: what is differnet here?